# Simplifying $\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify the following fraction:
>
> $$\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-1}$$

How should I approach this? unlike $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2+b^2$?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

If it's a limit problem, choose $$\sqrt[3]{x+1}=y\implies x+1=?$$

Answer (score 5):

Depending what you mean by simplify: presumably, get rid of the denominator.

Let $y = \sqrt[3]{x+1}$ then

$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-1} = \frac{y^3 -1}{y-1} = y^2 + y +1 = (x+1)^{\frac23} + \sqrt[3]{x+1} + 1
$$